# R equivalent to SAS DO loop

Tags: r, loops, sas

ID  Type    Sales   Date
1   1   $ 5,027 18-Jan-2016
2   1   $ 2,646 10-Nov-2012
3   1   $ 7,549 11-Feb-2018
4   2   $ 4,536 18-Feb-2016
5   2   $ 3,118 26-Aug-2017
6   3   $ 9,815 07-Jun-2017
7   3   $ 885   15-Dec-2017
8   3   $ 2,911 10-Nov-2017
9   3   $ 1,823 12-Oct-2015
10  4   $ 5,723 04-Jul-2014
11  5   $ 2,612 31-Mar-2015
12  5   $ 3,344 06-Jan-2016
13  5   $ 4,215 22-May-2016
14  6   $ 5,500 23-Mar-2018

To split the above dataset (Main) into Type wise, we may use the following macro. How to do the same in R.
Thanks in advance.

```
%MACRO split;  

%DO m = 1 %TO 6 ;  


DATA type_%eval(&m) ;  


SET main ;  


IF Type = &m then output type_%eval(&m) ;  


RUN ;  

%END ;  

%MEND split ;  

%split ;
```

ID  Type    Sales   Date
1   1   $ 5,027 18-Jan-2016
2   1   $ 2,646 10-Nov-2012
3   1   $ 7,549 11-Feb-2018

ID  Type    Sales   Date
4   2   $ 4,536 18-Feb-2016
5   2   $ 3,118 26-Aug-2017

ID  Type    Sales   Date
6   3   $ 9,815 07-Jun-2017
7   3   $ 885   15-Dec-2017
8   3   $ 2,911 10-Nov-2017
9   3   $ 1,823 12-Oct-2015

this will give me following datasets Type1, Type2, Type3 ..... Type6

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split`. If your data frame is called `df`, do

```
df.list <- split(df, df$Type)
```

This gives you a list of data frames. You can get individual data frames by using `$` and the value of `Type` (as below). Since these names don't follow the convention of not starting with a number, you have to put ticks or quotes around them

```
df.list$'1'
```

You can also use the list indexing e.g. `df.list[3]` for the third `data.frame`. In your example, by coincidence, these align at times e.g. `df.list$'1'` is the same as `df.list[1]`.